# Unable to load pickled custom estimator sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, dill, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have a sklearn pipeline that uses custom column transformer, estimator and different lambda functions.

Because Pickle cannot serialize the lambda functions, I am using dill.

Here is the custom estimator I have:

```
class customOLS(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, ols):
        self.estimator_ols = ols

    def fit(self, X, y):
        X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        y = pd.DataFrame(y)
        print('---- Training OLS')
        self.estimator_ols = self.estimator_ols(y,X).fit()
        #print('---- Training LR')
        #self.estimator_lr = self.estimator_lr.fit(X,y)
        return self

    def get_estimators(self):
        return self.estimator_ols #, self.estimator_lr
                
    def predict_ols(self, X):
        res = self.estimator_ols.predict(X)
        return res

pipeline2 = Pipeline(
        steps=[
            ('dropper', drop_cols),
            ('remover',feature_remover),
            ("preprocessor", preprocess_ppl),
            ("estimator", customOLS(sm.OLS))
            ]
    )
```

This is how I serilize it (I have to use open() otherwise it gives unsupportedOperation read write):

```
with open('data/baseModel_LR.joblib',"wb") as f:
        dill.dump(pipeline2, f)
```

But when I try to load the pickled object:

```
with open('data/baseModel_LR.joblib',"rb") as f:
        model = dill.load(f)
model
```

I get this error related to custom estimator:

> AttributeError: 'customOLS' object has no attribute 'ols'

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [do i need to use exactly same attribute names to properties in custom preprocessing class which inherit scikit learn BaseEstimator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74579336/do-i-need-to-use-exactly-same-attribute-names-to-properties-in-custom-preprocess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies on these two lines:

```py
    def __init__(self, ols):
        self.estimator_ols = ols
```

Here's an excerpt from the sklearn documentation, which explains why this won't work:

> All scikit-learn estimators have `get_params` and `set_params` functions. The `get_params` function takes no arguments and returns a dict of the `__init__` parameters of the estimator, together with their values.

[Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#get-params-and-set-params).

So, if you have a parameter named `ols` in your constructor, sklearn assumes that you have an attribute on your object, called `ols`. When you call `get_params()` on your object, (and `repr()` does call that) then that extracts the name of each variable from the constructor.

To fix it, change the constructor to this:

```py
    def __init__(self, estimator_ols):
        self.estimator_ols = estimator_ols
```

When I do that, I am able to save and load the pipeline.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer. Just so I understand, this means that if I have a variable xyz in a constructor then this object needs to be on the object i.e I can add self.xyz in the init, then it works as well.

Comment: @Obiii That's my understanding, yes.