# Getting the error 'Assignment4Transformer' object has no attribute 'y' running a pipeline on a fit.transform

Tags: pandas, numpy, class-transformer

Here's my data:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
1.5 2.354152979 COLD    593 0.75
2.5 3.31404772  WARM    340 2.083333333
3.5 4.021604459 COLD    551 4.083333333
4.5     COLD    2368    6.75
5.5 5.847601001 WARM    2636    10.08333333
6.5 7.229910044 WARM    2779    14.08333333
7.5 7.997255234 HOT 1057    18.75
8.5 9.203946542 COLD    819 24.08333333
9.5 10.33534766 WARM    3349    
10.5    11.11214192 HOT 3235    36.75
11.5    11.75961084 WARM    216 44.08333333
12.5    12.62909577 WARM    2529    52.08333333
13.5    14.08258887 COLD    1735    60.75
14.5    14.65767801 HOT 1254    70.08333333
15.5        HOT 1245    80.08333333
16.5    17.18411403 WARM    310 90.75
17.5    17.80077555 HOT 201 102.0833333
18.5    18.57886101 HOT 1767    114.0833333
```

I was supposed to create a transformer that accepted any array to be used in a pipeline. I'm at the point to where I'm calling the fit_transform() method on the original custom_transform data to obtain the final, clean data. Then saving the output data into a variable called data_trans.
So this is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

fileName = "CustomTransformerData.csv"
custom_transform = pd.read_csv("CustomTransformerData.csv")

data_num = custom_transform.drop(['x3'], axis = 1); #holds numeric features

data_cat = custom_transform.drop(['x1', 'x2', 'x4', 'x5'], axis = 1); #holds categorical features

#importing sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin




##creating the transformer
class Assignment4Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, drop_x4 = True, y=None):
        self.drop_x4 = drop_x4 #flag to drop the x4 column
    
    def fit(self, custom_transform, y=None): #finding the optimal set of parameters
        return self
    
    def transform(self, custom_transform):
        x6 = custom_transform[:, 0]**3 / custom_transform[:, 3] #creating new column at end
        if self.drop_x4:
            custom_transform = np.delete(custom_transform, 2, axis=1)
        return np.c_[custom_transform, x6]

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline #importing the pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer #importing the SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler #importing the preprocessor



num_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = "mean")),
                ('custom_trans', Assignment4Transformer()),
                ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())])


std_scaler = num_pipeline.fit_transform(data_num) #produces 1.5 - 18.5 arrays (Quick testing)

data_num_trans = num_pipeline.fit_transform(data_num)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

cat_encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False) #as instructed

data_cat_OHE = cat_encoder.fit_transform(data_cat) #2x15 array

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

num_attribs = list(data_num) #adjusting the attributes
cat_attribs = ["x3"]`




full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs), #constructing the pipeline for the attributes
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs), #adding the categorical data back in 
])
data_trans = full_pipeline.fit_transform(custom_transform) #ERROR
```

I'm not sure why the error now when everything else ran smoothly.

The output should be:

```
[[-1.64 -1.73 -1.2  -1.59  0.    0.  ]
 [-1.45 -1.53 -1.16 -1.4   0.    1.  ]
 [-1.25 -1.38 -1.1  -1.21  0.    0.  ]
 [-1.06  0.   -1.03 -1.02  0.    0.  ]
 [-0.87 -0.99 -0.93 -0.83  0.    1.  ]
 [-0.67 -0.7  -0.82 -0.64  0.    1.  ]
 [-0.48 -0.53 -0.69 -0.45  1.    0.  ]
 [-0.29 -0.28 -0.54 -0.26  0.    0.  ]
 [-0.1  -0.04  0.   -0.61  0.    1.  ]
 [ 0.1   0.13 -0.18  0.13  1.    0.  ]
 [ 0.29  0.27  0.03  0.32  0.    1.  ]
 [ 0.48  0.45  0.26  0.51  0.    1.  ]
 [ 0.67  0.76  0.5   0.7   0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.87  0.88  0.76  0.89  1.    0.  ]
 [ 1.06  0.    1.05  1.08  1.    0.  ]
 [ 1.25  1.42  1.35  1.27  0.    1.  ]
 [ 1.45  1.55  1.67  1.46  1.    0.  ]
 [ 1.64  1.71  2.01  1.65  1.    0.  ]]
```

Full traceback error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    821             try:
--> 822                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    823             except queue.Empty:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    167                 if not self._qsize():
--> 168                     raise Empty
    169             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/5v/f6glw1515sqbvblc482qs47c0000gn/T/ipykernel_2486/1086226106.py in <module>
----> 1 data_trans = full_pipeline.fit_transform(custom_transform) #ERROR

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    688         self._validate_remainder(X)
    689 
--> 690         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    691 
    692         if not result:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted, column_as_strings)
    619         )
    620         try:
--> 621             return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    622                 delayed(func)(
    623                     transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1041             # remaining jobs.
   1042             self._iterating = False
-> 1043             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1044                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1045 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    831                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    832 
--> 833                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    834                 if len(islice) == 0:
    835                     return False

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    621             return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    622                 delayed(func)(
--> 623                     transformer=clone(trans) if not fitted else trans,
    624                     X=_safe_indexing(X, column, axis=1),
    625                     y=y,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     85     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     86     for name, param in new_object_params.items():
---> 87         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
     88     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
     89     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     63     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
     64     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
---> 65         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
     66     elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     67         if not safe:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     63     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
     64     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
---> 65         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
     66     elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     67         if not safe:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     63     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
     64     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
---> 65         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
     66     elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     67         if not safe:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     63     # XXX: not handling dictionaries
     64     if estimator_type in (list, tuple, set, frozenset):
---> 65         return estimator_type([clone(e, safe=safe) for e in estimator])
     66     elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     67         if not safe:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     83 
     84     klass = estimator.__class__
---> 85     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     86     for name, param in new_object_params.items():
     87         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in get_params(self, deep)
    209         out = dict()
    210         for key in self._get_param_names():
--> 211             value = getattr(self, key)
    212             if deep and hasattr(value, "get_params") and not isinstance(value, type):
    213                 deep_items = value.get_params().items()

AttributeError: 'Assignment4Transformer' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Also, this sounds like a get_params() issue. You have an argument, `y`, which is not saved as `self.y`. This will cause problems anywhere that get_params() is called. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/74579336/530160

Comment: Adding the full error above.